# What is the way to handle the user disaproval of a fb app?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps

I wrote a simple facebook app, and when I first access the app, but I dis-allow it, i.e, when I click cancel (See the following shot)

[image]

...I get redirected to a page that shows the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The above error usually occurs when you try to load the App Center page for your application when the app actually doesn't have the `App Details` settings set.

So, instead of trying to load the App Center URL for the application, try loading the following:

```
https://apps.facebook.com/YOUR_APPLICATION
```

And if you want the App Center URL to work, you'll need to fill the App Details tab settings, and then submit your App for review.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Amal, I haven't submited the app for review yet, so I will finish it and then test.

Comment: Hi Amal, hope you are ok. I wasn't able to test because I gave control of the app to another developer and that campaigns seems to be ended already. I will try to re-create this with a new app and let you know. Thanks again for your help!